# Did Iron Man take any blame for the events of Avengers vs X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men, avengers, iron-man, avengers-vs-x-men

After the events of Avengers vs X-Men

> Xavier is dead

and Wolverine is pretty clear on who to blame - Cyclops.

But without the actions of Iron Man in *Avengers vs X-Men* #5:

[image]

The Phoenix Force would have gone into Hope, instead of the "Phoenix Five":

[image]

Was Iron Man ever really held accountable for this? I'm particularly interested in any Iron Man / Wolverine interaction.

> Especially considering the resolution of Avengers vs X-Men was to get the Phoenix Force into Hope anyway.

Comment: To be fair, Wolverine would blame *anything* on Scott.

Answer (score 1):

### No. (Or, probably not.)

There is no reference to Iron Man taking the fall for the mentioned actions in Avengers vs. X-Men.

There is no definitive reference, however, but it could be implied or a headcanon that Iron Man does take the fall. **But, in no comics on the Avengers vs. X-Men timeline did Iron Man take backlash for the events of the timeline.**